# Multiplication in LC3

Tags: assembly, multiplication, lc3

How would one multiply in LC3 taking into account that numbers in registers could be negative? Additionally, how would one multiply a value in a register by an integer?
For example lets say R2 = R1 * R0
If both numbers inside registers were positive the LC3 code would look something like this:

```
.ORIG x3000
LD R2, ZERO
LD R0, M0
LD R1, M1
ST R1, SaveR1
LOOP BRz DONE
ADD R2, R2, R0
ADD R1, R1, #-1
BR LOOP
DONE ST R2, RESULT
LD R1, SaveR1
HALT
SaveR1 .BLKW 1
M0 .FILL x1011
M1 .FILL x0005
.END
```

How would I implement multiplication if either R1 or R0 was negative? How can I check to see if both are negative? Additionally, how can I implement multiplication by a number, such as 4? R1 = R0 * 4.

Comment: If your product is only one register wide, same width as the inputs, you can treat them as unsigned because LC-3 uses 2's complement signed integers.  The result will be the same.  (Only the upper half of a N x N => 2N-bit product differs between signed and unsigned multiply on a 2's complement machine.)  If you're using a slow algorithm like adding N times, that could be very slow for small negative numbers (which are huge unsigned numbers), but a shift-and-add algorithm doesn't have that problem; fixed time regardless of input.

Comment: To multiply by power-of-2 constants like `4`, `add r2,r2,r2` ; `add r2,r2,r2` (left-shift twice to double the number twice, i.e. multiply by 2^2 = 4).

Comment: As Peter says, basic math: 4n = n + n + n + n, and also, let m = 2n = n + n, so 4n = 2m = m+m.

Comment: As for checking if a number is negative, look at the leftmost bit of that register, if it's a 1 then it's negative. (Of course, if your data is intended to be unsigned, it's not really negative, but you know what I mean.)